Can blender make use of an integrated GPU and a discrete GPU at the same time to speed up renders?
I was thinking about getting an APU for my next build and was curious if I also get a discrete GPU can blender make use of both kind of like a dual GPU render? Would there be any performance increases if it's possible?

I doubt any integrated gpu has any better performance gain than using the cpu as is, which is already possible to use alongside the dedicated gpu. Hybrid rendering performance gain is really variable, depending the particular hardware and the scene it can be a slight speed boost , nothing, or even slower. And in all cases, higher electricity consumption, unusable machine while rendering, higher risks of overheating (so definitely don't do it without a solid cooling system).
